# Stock exchange to trade company's own stock with API

Tags: stock, trading

Is there a US-based stock exchange, where a small company could sell/buy back its own stock programmatically in near real-time?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to register with a clearing house who will provide you with api access to the exchange(s) that your company trades on.

Comment: Can you give any data flow examples?